# Как передать данные из сайта в приложение?

Tags: android, база-данных, веб-сайт

Передали в пользование сайт с большим количеством товаров. Задача написать приложение (просмотр товаров, отзывы, корзина...интернет магазин в общем).
Небольшой опыт в написании приложения есть, но не работал  с БД. Основная задача разобраться каким  образом мне вытаскивать инфу с сайта .
HTTP запросы?
Парсинг?(плохой вариант)
WebView?
Или же просто подключиться к БД и вытянуть с нее все фото, описание товара и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всё правильно понимаете, но давайте немного глубже разберём каждый пункт.

HTTP Запросы (REST API) - один из самых распространённых вариантов при создании приложения. Компании создают так называемые API сервера, которые предоставляют общую бизнес логику для работы приложений клиентов. При такой архитектуре, может быть целый зоопарк различных клиентов, которые могут одновременно выполнять запросы к серверу, а он в свою очередь выдавать необходимую информацию. Клиентами могут быть Web (Angular, React или же приложения на обычном JQuery), Android, iOS приложения, это не так важно, главное чтобы у них был доступ к сети интернет и к вашему серверу.

Парсинг - вы правильно отметили, что это не лучший вариант, при смене структуры HTML страницы, вам придётся каждый раз переписывать свои приложения. На долгую перспективу такое решение не подойдёт.

WebView - Это самый простой вариант, ваше приложение будет ограниченным мобильным браузером, где можно будет открыть только определённое количество страниц + вы сможете немного доработать взаимодействие с сайтом добавив компоненты из Android\iOS SDK. Здесь подводные камни кроются в адаптивности разметки страницы, такой вариант подойдёт, если сайт хорошо открывается в мобильных браузерах, однако если вёрстка расчитана на Desktop браузеры, то это решение будет работать ничуть не лучше, чем простое открытие интернет страницы на смартфоне.

БД - Подключение к БД напрямую также возможно, JDBC позволяет подключаться через сеть, однако это уже прямой вопрос к безопасности, так как такие клиенты должны иметь доступ к подключению. Любой код, который размещается на клиентской машине (компьютере, телефоне, холодильнике и т.д.), может быть раскодирован, человек может получить доступ к вашей базе, что скорее всего не в ваших интересах. Более того, изменение структуры БД повлечёт изменение кодовой базы и на стороне клиентов.

Таким образом, субъективно лучший вариант API сервер, который займётся всеми проблемами при изменении структур данных, защите информации и т.п.

P. S. Весь написанный выше текст, субъективен, у других пользователей могут возникать и другие мысли на тот или иной счёт.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ! Теперь осталось разобраться как сделать API сервера)